# An SSH tunnel via multiple hops

Tags: ssh, tunnel

Tunneling data over SSH is pretty straight-forward:

```
ssh -D9999 username@example.com
```

sets up port 9999 on your `localhost` as a tunnel to `example.com`, but I have a more specific need:

- I am working locally on `localhost`
- `host1` is accessible to `localhost`
- `host2` only accepts connections from `host1`
- I need to create a tunnel from `localhost` to `host2`

Effectively, I want to create a "multi-hop" SSH tunnel. How can I do this? Ideally, I'd like to do this without needing to be superuser on *any* of the machines.

Comment: What did you use it for? I want to use it for socks proxy. Will it work?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the tunneled connection as a SOCKS proxy, unless `host2` denies forwarding

Comment: I was thinking about creating a wrapper over SSH that would set up that using multiple use of ProxyCommand.

Comment: @prongs Have you managed to use this for SOCKS proxy (all those years ago)?

Answer (score 436, accepted):

You basically have three possibilities:

1. Tunnel from `localhost` to `host1`:

   ```
   ssh -L 9999:host2:1234 -N host1
   ```

   As noted above, the connection from `host1` to `host2` will not be secured.
2. Tunnel from `localhost` to `host1` and from `host1` to `host2`:

   ```
   ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 host1 ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N host2
   ```

   This will open a tunnel from `localhost` to `host1` and another tunnel from `host1` to `host2`. However the port `9999` to `host2:1234` can be used by anyone on `host1`. This may or may not be a problem.
3. Tunnel from `localhost` to `host1` and from `localhost` to `host2`:

   ```
   ssh -L 9998:host2:22 -N host1
   ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N -p 9998 localhost
   ```

   This will open a tunnel from `localhost` to `host1` through which the SSH service on `host2` can be used. Then a second tunnel is opened from `localhost` to `host2` through the first tunnel.

Normally, I'd go with option 1. If the connection from `host1` to `host2` needs to be secured, go with option 2. Option 3 is mainly useful to access a service on `host2` that is only reachable from `host2` itself.

Comment: I want to do browsing this way. Which one's best? I tried first one but it didn't work. I set a socks proxy in my browser localhost:1234 but no luck. :( please help..

Comment: @prongs try option 3

Comment: is there a way to forward my public key from localhost, through the tunnel of host 1, on to host2?

Comment: @Noli If you use ssh-agent (which you should), you can forward it through the connections using the `-A` option to ssh.

Comment: I have an application that (apparently) uses its own ssh client to connect over SFTP (PHPStorm). Can you explain whether these options will help me? I can't use authorized keys because of this and I only have a single password field. It's not going to prompt me.

Comment: What means normally? The reason host1 exists is in most cases to securely enter host2. If you don't secure the host1-host2 connection you violate the security premises, or not?

Comment: Notes: Option `1` if you using `OSX` then remove `-N` option which doesn't work

Comment: Is it only me, but does option 2 leave one `ssh` listening on `host1` when one `Ctrl-C`s the local `ssh`? I am unable to execute the command twice in a row without going to `host1` and killing the last `ssh` process which is still listening o post `9999`.

Comment: @musically_ut - that's correct, the 2nd ssh command is backgrounded on host1, so if you want to reconnect locally to it, you only need to rerun the first part again. If you add `-f`, it will immediately background locally, thus `ssh -f -L 9999:localhost:9999 host1` will reconnect if you pressed ctrl-c in first case. Or add `-f` to the original double ssh command when first running it to background everything immediately.

Comment: When I tried option 3, and ran `ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N -p 9998 localhost`, which password am I supposed to give? I tried both the passwords of the local and remote users, none worked.

Comment: What exactly is insecure about option 1? Where is 'above'?

Comment: Hello, how can I extend this solution to another server? I'm trying to do the forwarding using vnc. Right now, I have a `localhost`, `guard`, `jump_host`, `target_server` and I want to port forward from `localhost` to `target_server`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, the third option worked perfectly for me! :)

Comment: The `-N` parameter in the above command means that ssh won't execute a remote command, meaning that a shell won't be opened on the remote machine (`host1`)

Comment: I wanted to open the tunnels, start a browser, and have it clean up when the browser is closed. I used the 2nd option with `-t -t` parameters to make sure the 2nd tunnel closed when the process was killed. My full script (I had to use `-4` to ensure ipv4): `ssh -4 -t -t -L 9999:localhost:9999 host1 ssh -4 -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N host2 &` `google-chrome "https://localhost:9999"` `kill -9 $!`

Answer (score 202):

There is an [excellent answer explaining the use of the `ProxyCommand` configuration directive for SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine):

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` (see `man 5 ssh_config` for details):

```
Host host2
  ProxyCommand ssh host1 -W %h:%p
```

Then `ssh host2` will automatically tunnel through `host1` (also works with X11 forwarding etc.).

This also works for an entire class of hosts e.g. identified by domain:

```
Host *.mycompany.com
  ProxyCommand ssh gateway.mycompany.com -W %h:%p
```

## Update

[OpenSSH 7.3 introduces](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) a `ProxyJump` directive, simplifying the first example to

```
Host host2
  ProxyJump host1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this conditionally? I only want to do this sometimes. Also, this is specifically for commands, but I'm looking for something for all of port 22 (ssh, sftp, etc).

Comment: @Stephane what do you mean by *specifically for commands*? Your SSH config is used by anything using `ssh`, including `git`, `sftp` etc. afaik.

Comment: @Stephane I'm not aware of a way of enabling this conditionally (e.g. only when you're outside the network of the target host). I set this option for all hosts in question in a configuration block and then (un)comment the line as needed. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Hmmm can I cause ssh to use a different config file if I want it to? Thanks for these replies!

Comment: @Stephane sure: `ssh -F /path/to/altconfig`. Beware this will ignore the system wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: An easy way to make settings "conditional" is to define two different hosts in .ssh/config, that have the same HostName. Connect to host2-tunnel when you want the tunnel, and host2 when you don't.

Comment: This is awesome answer !! good job !

Comment: Has anyone had any luck making this work using the openssh for windows distro here: http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html?  It seems like I need to give it a full cygwin path to ssh but I attempted using the following andstill had no luck:

 ProxyCommand "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/OpenSSH/bin/ssh" ...

Comment: ProxyJump is amazing!

Comment: Easier than using `ProxyJump` is `-J` switch.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Depends on your use case: for one-off use `-J` is certainly easier than modifying your SSH config. However if you *always* need the proxy to access a certain host I find it easier to only change SSH config once.

Comment: Is there an elegant way to solve this if `host1`'s public key is encrypted?  (elegant = without having remove the encryption?)

Comment: @AloisMahdal Why would the host key be encrypted? It's a public key for a reason.

Comment: @kynan, my bad, I meant *private* key there.

Comment: @AloisMahdal I don't understand how that is related. *Your* SSH client needs to be able to read *your*, the host's SSHD needs to be able to read the host's private key - irrespective of using `ProxyJump` or not.

Comment: @kynan I'm at `host0`, and want to connect to `host2`, which IP-wise will only talk to `host1`.  I can already do `ssh host1`, and from the interactive shell just do `ssh host2`, answer the passphrase, and I'm there.  Now: if I say `ssh host1 -J host2`  it fails because it won't forward the password prompt necessary to unlock the key on `host1`. (IIRC I've been able to do that the other day with the key on `host1` being unencrypted.)

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup, but would recommend using SSH keys for authentication, SSH agent and agent forwarding (`ssh -A`).

Comment: If you end up here as a Windows user, the ssh command just needs a little fine tuning to work: `ProxyCommand ssh.exe hostB -W %h:%p`, i.e., `ssh.exe` instead of `ssh`. As of this writing `ProxyJump` is not working yet on Windows (but might be fixed as [described here](https://fabian-voith.de/2020/04/16/using-openssh-on-windows-10-and-handling-passwords/)).

Answer (score 83):

OpenSSH v7.3 onward supports a `-J` switch and a `ProxyJump` option, which allow one or more comma-separated jump hosts, so, you can simply do this now:

```
ssh -J jumpuser1@jumphost1,jumpuser2@jumphost2,...,jumpuserN@jumphostN user@host
```

Comment: ssh -J user1@host1  -YC4c arcfour,blowfish-cbc user2@host2 firefox -no-remote
This will speed up getting firefox from host2 to localhost.

Comment: I had no idea you could do it like this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I would add that you can specify ports: `-J user1@host1:port1,user2@host2:port2,...`

Answer (score 21):

We have one ssh gateway into our private network. If I'm outside and want a remote shell on a machine inside the private network, I would have to ssh into the gateway and from there to the private machine.

To automate this procedure, I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -f -L some_port:private_machine:22 user@gateway "sleep 10" && ssh -p some_port private_user@localhost
```

What is happening:

1. Establish a tunnel for the ssh protocol (port 22) to the private machine.
2. Only if this is successful, ssh into the private machine using the tunnel. (the && operater ensures this).
3. After closing the private ssh session, I want the ssh tunnel to close, too. This is done via the "sleep 10" trick. Usually, the first ssh command would close after 10 seconds, but during this time, the second ssh command will have established a connection using the tunnel. As a result, the first ssh command keeps the tunnel open until the following two conditions are satisfied: sleep 10 is finished and the tunnel is no longer used.

Comment: Very clever!!! LOVE IT!

Answer (score 20):

After reading the above and glueing everything together, I've created the following Perl script (save it as mssh in /usr/bin and make it executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$iport = 13021;
$first = 1;

foreach (@ARGV) {
  if (/^-/) {
    $args .= " $_";
  }
  elsif (/^((.+)@)?([^:]+):?(\d+)?$/) {
    $user = $1;
    $host = $3;
    $port = $4 || 22;
    if ($first) {
      $cmd = "ssh ${user}${host} -p $port -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no";
      $args = '';
      $first = 0;
    }
    else {
      $cmd .= " -L $iport:$host:$port";
      push @cmds, "$cmd -f sleep 10 $args";
      $cmd = "ssh ${user}localhost -p $iport -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no";
      $args = '';
      $iport ++;
    }
  }
}
push @cmds, "$cmd $args";

foreach (@cmds) {
  print "$_\n";
  system($_);
}
```

Usage:

To access HOSTC via HOSTA and HOSTB (same user):

```
mssh HOSTA HOSTB HOSTC
```

To access HOSTC via HOSTA and HOSTB and use non-default SSH-portnumbers and different users:

```
mssh user1@HOSTA:1234 user2@HOSTB:1222 user3@HOSTC:78231
```

To access HOSTC via HOSTA and HOSTB and use X-forwarding:

```
mssh HOSTA HOSTB HOSTC -X
```

To access port 8080 on HOSTC via HOSTA and HOSTB:

```
mssh HOSTA HOSTB -L8080:HOSTC:8080
```

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: I seriously cannot thank you enough, this script makes my life easier on a daily basis. The only thing I changed was to add int(rand(1000)) to iport, to allow multiple instances to run at the same time. I definitely owe you a beer.

Comment: This works really well. A further improvement would be to resolve HOSTB, HOSTC etc using localhost's /etc/hosts and ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Also I second Mala's comment. Without the randomized port, if you then try to `mssh HOSTA HOSTD` you'll actually end up at HOSTB (and maybe won't realise..)

Answer (score 17):

I did what I *think* you wanted to do with

```
ssh -D 9999 -J host1 host2
```

I'm prompted for both passwords, then I can use localhost:9999 for a SOCKS proxy to host2. It's the nearest I can think of to the example you showed in the first place.

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Comment: Didn't work for three hosts

Answer (score 14):

My answer is really the same as all the other answers here, but, I wanted to clarify the usefulness of `~/.ssh/config` and ProxyJump.

To illustrate this, suppose I needed to get to a destination in 3 hops, and, for each hop, I needed to specify username, host, port, and identity. To get to the final computer I may have used multiple `ssh` commands and the identity files are stored on multiple computers:

```bash
[yourpc] $ ssh user1@host1 -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/pem/identity1.pem
[host1] $ ssh user2@host2 -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/pem/identity2.pem
[host2] $ ssh user3@host3 -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/pem/identity3.pem
[host3] $ exit
[host2] $ exit
[host1] $ exit
[yourpc] $
```

If I want to use a single `ssh` command to go from your PC to any of the hosts. I can use `~/.ssh/config` config file which contains the details of each host and all identities needed to access each host on my host PC. The `ProxyJump` keyword is used to specify an intermediate host is needed to arrive at the target host.

```
Host hop1
    User user1
    HostName host1
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pem/identity1.pem

Host hop2
    User user2
    HostName host2
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pem/identity2.pem
    ProxyJump hop1

Host hop3
    User user3
    HostName host3
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pem/identity3.pem
    ProxyJump hop2
```

From your computer, you can test each jump individually, i.e.

```bash
[yourpc] $ ssh hop1 # will go from your PC to host1 in a single step
[host1] $ exit
[yourpc] $ ssh hop2 # will go from your PC to host2 via host1 (i.e. two steps)
[host2] $ exit
[yourpc] $ ssh hop3 # will go from your PC to host3 via host1 and host2 (i.e. three steps)
[host3] $ exit
[yourpc] $
```

Another cool thing about the `~/.ssh/config` file is that this will also enable `sftp` file transfers via any series of hops, e.g.

```bash
[yourpc] $ sftp hop1 # for file transfers between your PC and host1
Connected to hop1.
sftp> quit
[yourpc] $ sftp hop2 # for file transfers between your PC and host2
Connected to hop2.
sftp> quit
[yourpc] $ sftp hop3 # for file transfers between your PC and host3
Connected to hop3.
sftp> quit
```

References:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html

Answer (score 9):

This answer is similar to kynan, as it involves the use of ProxyCommand. But it's more convenient to use IMO.

If you have netcat installed in your hop machines you can add this snippet to your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *+*
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | sed 's/+[^+]*$//;s/\([^+%%]*\)%%\([^+]*\)$/\2 -l \1/;s/:/ -p /') nc $(echo %h | sed 's/^.*+//;/:/!s/$/ %p/;s/:/ /')
```

Then

```
ssh -D9999 host1+host2 -l username
```

will do what you asked.

I came here looking for the original place where I read this trick. I'll post a link when I find it.

Comment: I believe this is the origination of the trick: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host

Answer (score 4):

```
ssh -L 9999:host2:80 -R 9999:localhost:9999 host1
```

> -L 9999:host2:80

Means bind to localhost:9999 and any packet sent to localhost:9999 forward it to host2:80

> -R 9999:localhost:9999

Means any packet received by host1:9999 forward it back to localhost:9999

Comment: Brilliant, most simple answer to make a tunnel so you can access the application on host2 directly from localhost:9999

Comment: Following this answer, I get a `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`  error message.

Answer (score 4):

Only this helped me on more than two hosts:

```
ssh -L 6010:localhost:6010 user1@host1 \
-t ssh -L 6010:localhost:6010 user2@host2 \
-t ssh -L 6010:localhost:6010 user3@host3
```

It will prompt you with three passwords.

[Inspired by this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/791997/494014)

Comment: ssh -L 33033:localhost:33032 user1@host1 -t ssh -L 33032:localhost:3306 user2@host2

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use port forwarding to access a service on `host2` from `localhost`. A good guide is located [here](http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/Port_Forwarding.html). Excerpt:

> There are two kinds of port forwarding: local and remote forwarding. They are also called outgoing and incoming tunnels, respectively. Local port forwarding forwards traffic coming to a local port to a specified remote port.
>
> For example, if you issue the command
>
> ```
> ssh2 -L 1234:localhost:23 username@host
> ```
>
> all traffic coming to port 1234 on the client will be forwarded to port 23 on the server (host). Note that localhost will be resolved by the sshdserver after the connection is established. In this case localhost therefore refers to the server (host) itself.
>
> Remote port forwarding does the opposite: it forwards traffic coming to a remote port to a specified local port.
>
> For example, if you issue the command
>
> ```
> ssh2 -R 1234:localhost:23 username@host
> ```
>
> all traffic which comes to port 1234 on the server (host) will be forwarded to port 23 on the client (localhost).

In your cast, replace `localhost` in the example with `host2` and `host` with `host1`.

Comment: according to that article, the connection will only be secured until the middle machine (host1). Is there a way to make sure the whole thing stays secure?

Comment: I've never tried this, but if host1 and host2 are both ssh servers, you might be able to set up a tunnel from host1 to host2, then set up a tunnel from localhost to host1 for the same service (getting your local and remote ports right). I don't know if that's possible in one command from localhost.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I will go through a concrete example. You just need to replace computers' hostnames, usernames and passwords by yours.

### Problem statement

Let's assume we have the following network topology:

```
our local computer <---> server 1 <---> server 2
```

For the sake of concreteness, let's assume we have the following computers' hostnames, usernames and passwords:

```
LocalPC            <--->  hostname: mit.edu         <---> hec.edu
                          username: bob                   username: john 
                          password: dylan123              password: doe456
```

Goal: we want to set up a SOCKS proxy that listens on port `9991` of `LocalPC` so that each time a connection on `LocalPC` is initiated from port  `9991` it goes  through `mit.edu` then `hec.edu`.

Example of use case: `hec.edu` has an HTTP server that is only accessible on  http://127.0.0.1:8001, for security reasons. We would like to be able to visit  http://127.0.0.1:8001 by opening a web browser on `LocalPC`.

---

### Configuration

In `LocalPC`, add in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host HEC
    HostName hec.edu
    User john
    ProxyCommand ssh bob@mit.edu -W %h:%p
```

Then in the terminal of `LocalPC`, run:

```
ssh -D9991 HEC
```

It will ask you the password of `bob` on `mit.edu` (i.e., `dylan123`), then it will ask you the password of `john` on `hec.edu` (i.e., `doe456`).

At that point, the SOCKS proxy is now running on port `9991` of `LocalPC`.

For example, if you want to visit a webpage on `LocalPC` using the SOCKS proxy, you can do in Firefox:

[image]

Some remarks:

- in `~/.ssh/config`, `HEC` is the connection name: you may change it to anything you want.
- The `-D9991` tells `ssh` to set up a SOCKS4 proxy on port `9991`.

Comment: `ssh -D9991 HEC` simply sshs into hec.edu here

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is **Jump Proxy**:

```
ssh -N -A -J user1@host1 -D 8123 user2@host2
```

then you can use `SOCKS` in local via `127.0.0.1:8123`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH into both machines, take a look at ssh's ProxyCommand directive. This will let you go straight from localhost into host2 (in one easy command if you use public keys!!). Then you can do whatever you want with host2.

http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/03/1916/

Answer (score 0):

The option 2 of the [best answer](https://superuser.com/a/97007/72337) could be used with different ssh users than the current one aka : user@host

```
    export local_host_port=30000
    export host1_user=xyz
    export host1=mac-host
    export host1_port=30000
    export host2=192.168.56.115
    export host2_user=ysg
    export host2_port=13306

    # Tunnel from localhost to host1 and from host1 to host2
    # you could chain those as well to host3 ... hostn
    ssh -tt -L $local_host_port:localhost:$host1_port $host1_user@$host1 \
    ssh -tt -L $host1_port:localhost:$host2_port $host2_user@$host2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did

```
localhost$ ssh -D 9999 host1
host1$ ssh -L 8890:localhost:8890 host2
```

where `host2:8890` is running on a Jupyter Notebook.

Then I configured Firefox to use `localhost:9999` as a SOCKS host.

So now I've got the notebook running on `host2` accessible by Firefox at `localhost:8890` on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The three options mentioned in the accepted answer didn't work for me at all. Since I don't have much permission over both hosts, and seem like our DevOps team has a pretty strict rules when comes to authentication and are doing MFA. Somehow the commands above cannot play well with our authentication.

The context is really similar to answers above though: I cannot ssh into production server directly, and have to do 1 hop using a jump server.

### Yet Another Solution - a naive one

I ended up doing it by a very naive way: instead of trying to run all the commands on my laptop, I run the commands **on each of the machine**, as below:

1. SSH into your jump server, then run `ssh -v -L 6969:localhost:2222 -N your-protected.dest.server`. If you're prompted with any password input, type it.
2. Now on your laptop, run `ssh -v -L 6969:localhost:6969 -N your-jump-server.host.name`. This will forward any of your request on port 6969 on your laptop, to the jump server. Then by turn, since we configured in our previous step, the jump server will again forward requests of port 6969 to port 2222 on the protected destination server.

You should see the command "hangs" there after printing some message - it means they're working! One exception - you should not see error message like `Could not request local forwarding.`, if you see that, then it's still not working :(. You can now try to fire request on port 6969 from your laptop, and see if it's working.

Hopefully if you are someone who failed all the methods above, perhaps you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`.

```
Host jump_host
  HostName example.com
  User <jump_host_user>
  IdentityFile <local/path/to/jump_id>

Host destination_host
  HostName <ip or url>
  User <destination_host_user>
  IdentityFile <local/path/to/id>
  ProxyJump jump_host
```

This will make the destination act as if you had direct access so that you can call

```
ssh -D9999 destination_host
```

Using these of course requires, that you add your `id_rsa.pub` into the `authorized_keys` file on the respective serves.