# Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, git, tunnel

SSH tunneling is very confusing to me.  I am wondering if I can do this in Linux.

I have 3 machines..

```
A. My local machine at home.
B. Machine at work that I can SSH into (middle man).
C. My desktop at work that I can only SSH into from machine B.
```

So I can SSH from A -> B and from B -> C, but not from A -> C.

Is there a way to setup an SSH tunnel from A through B, so when I run other SSH commands it they just work from my local machine A?  I am basically trying to clone a git repo from work to home (and I cannot install git on machine B).

Also, once setup.. How would I unset it as well?

Comment: i believe there's a duplicate question around somewhere but my search-fu is weak today.

Comment: that would be mine: http://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An SSH tunnel via multiple hops](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops)

Comment: If you're running Linux on machine A, use a tool called sshuttle, which allows you to selectively forward all traffic for C thru the A->B tunnel (assuming C is visible from B).

Answer (score 143):

Place this in your `.ssh/config` file on hostA (see [man 5 ssh_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) for details):

```
# .ssh/config on hostA:
Host hostC
    ProxyCommand ssh hostB -W %h:%p
```

Now the following command will automatically tunnel through hostB

```
hostA:~$ ssh hostC
```

You may like to add options like `-oCiphers=arcfour` and `-oClearAllForwardings=yes` to speed things up, since wrapping `ssh` inside `ssh` is computationally more expensive and the extra effort and the wrapper doesn't need to be as secure when it's tunneling already-encrypted traffic.

---

If you are using OpenSSH earlier than 5.3, the `-W` option is not available. In this case you can implement the above using netcat (`nc`):

```
ProxyCommand ssh hostB nc %h %p  # or netcat or whatever you have on hostB
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you. This solves a problem that has been eating me for the past 2 days:

hostC sits behind a firewall and has data I want to access from hostA, a laptop that can be anywhere in the world. hostB is also behind the same firewall with hostC, but it has an SSH port open to the world. Thus I can ssh from hostC -> hostB. I setup a reverse SSH tunnel between hostC & hostB, so I can also ssh from hostB -> hostC (forwarded through localhost). With your trick I can go from hostA -> hostC! It works seamlessly with SCP & Fugu on OSX! Thank you!

Comment: The `-W` option should be used instead of the `nc` option.

Comment: Which SSH should support `-W`, only the one on hostA (the origin) or also the one on hostB (the middle machine)?

Comment: For info, if you have multiple hosts you need to reach via the same `hostB`, it's possible to declare multiple `Host hostC` lines above the `ProxyCommand` making it super easy to access several hosts via the middle server.

Comment: If you end up here as a Windows user, the ssh command just needs a little fine tuning to work: `ProxyCommand ssh.exe hostB -W %h:%p`, i.e., `ssh.exe` instead of `ssh`.

Comment: PLEASE just use ProxyJump instead.  Much less complicated, and basically eliminates the possibility of security mistakes or unnecessary trust.  ProxyJump even lets you avoid agent forwarding most of the time (big security win).

Answer (score 10):

For interactive shell you can use this simple command:

```
ssh -J <user>@<hostB> <user>@<hostC>
```

The -J options is for **jump**.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Much simpler than the rest. Only available since OpenSSH 7.3 but that's a few years now.

Comment: If the hostB uses port≠22, you can use the syntax like `user@hostB:port` (this wouldn't work for hostC, where you have to use the usual `-p` option).

Comment: the port syntax is OK, but it's almost always better to learn the .ssh/config format.  this allows you to create aliases, control all sorts of parameters like port, default user, automatic application of proxyjump, etc.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit: This is the wrong approach. See [ephemient's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242172/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine/2242219#2242219) instead. This answer will work, but is potentially less secure and definitely less awesome.**

It sounds like you want a solution like the following:

```
ssh -L localhost:22:machinec:22 machineb
```

This will get you a shell on `machineb`. Leave this alone; minimize the terminal window.

Now, whenever you make an ssh connection to `localhost`, you will actually be connected to `machinec` through `machineb`. When you're done with the tunnel, just close the terminal in which you ran the above command.

Note that you'll need superuser privileges to run the command.

Comment: +1 Thanks Wesley. This is the real ssh tunneling answer. Here's an article about it: http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1816

Comment: On the whole, this is quite evil... but I've had to do this with ancient versions of OpenSSH, or other ssh clients.  You could pick some high port like 8022: this way it doesn't interfere with any ssh service on localhost, and doesn't require running as root.  Just add `-p 8022` to your ssh commands.  And it's braindead easy with git: use the URI `ssh://localhost:8022/path/to/repo.git`.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, since [OpenSSH 7.3](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) introduces a `ProxyJump` directive:

```
Host final
  ProxyJump intermediate
```

In example:

```
Host intermediate
  Hostname 10.0.0.42
  User root
Host final
  Hostname final.destination.com
  User foo
  ProxyJump intermediate
```

Then `ssh final` will jump through the intermediate machine.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a shell alias on A that causes ssh to occur on C

1. I assume that on A, you can type ssh me@b "ssh me@c hostname" and get back "C"
2. Make an alias sshc which expands sshc foo into ssh me@b "ssh me@c foo"
3. For exact syntax of creating the alias, consult superuser.com

Comment: You may have to add `-t` to the outer ssh's options if you want an interactive shell, since `ssh` assumes `-T` if it's given a command.

Comment: Note that this is a different category from the better answer (ProxyJump) because you are forming a new ssh connection on the intermediate box, rather than just a tunnel through which the local machine connects to the final host.  So you have to trust the intermedia, but don't with ProxyJump.  OTOH, this may be necessary/desired if the final box only accepts connections from the intermediate.

Answer (score 0):

If your employer provides a VPN, I'd recommend using that instead.

That way, you won't have to configure any applications specially (even ssh), and you can see any machine behind the firewall.  Additionally, all of your traffic will be encrypted by the VPN software, which will add security to any inadvertently or deliberately unencrypted traffic.

Comment: Sometimes its the VPN that is the reason we need these tricks...

Answer (score 0):

#### YASS Yet Another Simple Solution

```
ssh -f -L 2222:HostC_IP_or_Name:22 userOnB@hostB sleep 10 &&
    ssh -o HostKeyAlias=HostC -p 2222 userOnC@localhost
```

- First command open a ssh connection to *HostB* and tell *HostB* to forward connections from *localhost:2222* to *HostC:22*.
- the `-f` parameter tell SSH to go to background once connection established
- Second command open simply a client connection to *localhost:2222*
- Option *HostKeyAlias* are not required, but could help to prevent connection to wrong host
- Nota: command `sleep 10` are needed to maintain connection until second ssh command use forwarded port. Then first *ssh* will close when second *ssh* leave forwarded port.

you could now run subsequent ssh sessions:

```
ssh -o HostKeyAlias=HostC -p 2222 userOnC@localhost
```

#### Variant:

```
ssh -f -L 2222:HostC_IP_or_Name:22 userOnB@hostB sleep 10 &&
    ssh -M -S ~/.ssh/ssh_HostC22userOnC.sock -o HostKeyAlias=HostC -p 2222 userOnC@localhost
```

subsequent ssh sessions could be open by running:

```
ssh -S ~/.ssh/ssh_HostC22userOnC.sock userOnC@localhost
```

The main advantage of using -M and -S param is that only one connection is open from HostA to HostC, subsequent session won't authenticate again and run a lot quicker.

Comment: ControlMaster is a major win, but basically orthogonal to the question.  ControlMaster and Proxyjump is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Special case, mixed nix platforms:

hostA (linux)  ->  HostB (solaris)  ->  HostC (linux)

If need an X application on hostC, and the intermediate hop is on Solaris box... in this case I found the netcat (nc) needed on the ProxyCommand like so:

hostA:~$ vi .ssh/config:

```
Host hostC
    ProxyCommand ssh hostB nc %h %p       # where nc is netcat
```

Then automatic tunneling works:

hostA:~$ ssh hostC

Comment: happily obsoleted by ProxyJump