# interactive ssh session through gateway machine

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine.](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine)

I am looking to get an **interactive** ssh session on a remote machine, but must login via a gateway.

For example, right now I do the following:

```
@local % ssh <user>@<gateway>

@gateway % ssh <user>@<remote>
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in a single command from my local machine?  I have tried:

```
@local % ssh <user>@<gateway> 'ssh <user>@<remote>`
```

From the output i am indeed able to login, but do not get an interactive session.  I took inspiration for this attempt from using `ssh` to run a command remotely.

Comment: See [Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine.](http://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine).

Comment: Thanks - sorry I didn't find that one when searching earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

On your "gateway"...

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
Host remote
   ProxyCommand ssh -C gateway '/usr/bin/nc <remote.ip.address> 22'
```

On "local"...

```
$ ssh -t user@gateway 'ssh user@remote'
```

Comment: Thanks - I'd rather not make changes to the gateway machine as I have limited ability to access it beyond ssh login. I am not expert in the ways of modifying ssh config files so for me I'd rather make changes locally so that I can easily undo them in the event they don't work.  A local solution is suggested in http://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine as suggested by Gilles.