# Copy files across two SSH connections in one go (OS X, GUI or CLI)

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine.](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine)

I'm currently deploying a web app that requires files be copied to an internal server via a public facing server.

My current workflow looks like this:

- scp files to publicserver.example.com
- ssh to publicserver
- scp files to 10.2.68.10

What I'd really like to do is to copy files to the internal server in one go - either using a GUI, or via the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set up an alias for the internal server in `~/.ssh/config` as in http://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ssh to forward your port and then make scp use that port:

```
ssh -L yourport:internal.host:hostport user@publicserver.example.com
```

Then:

```
scp yourfile.xxx localhost:/directory -P yourport
```

I think that should already do the trick. You might want to take a look at `man ssh` and `man scp` if I got the arguments in the wrong way.