# running tail -f on a server which connects to another server over ssh

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, remote, tail

I have been using the following command to connect to a server, which connects to another server and runs tail -f on it:

```
ssh server1.com ssh server2.com tail -f file.log
```

This so far works fine. However, when I want to quit the tail process by pressing ctrl+c, I do not quit the tail process, but the ssh process. This leaves the tail process on the remote server running, which obviosly is not a very good idea.

Does any one have an idea how I could fix this command line? I also would be interested if there is tool, running on os x, that would allow to comfortably switch between viewing different files on the remote server.

Comment: Couldn't you use tmux or screen on the remote servers? That's what I've always done.

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952341/bash-perl-chained-ssh-commands-a-to-b-to-c) : To get it working in command line or in the shell, the ssh agent shall be forwarded too, eg using the ssh option "A" (see ssh man page), like :

ssh -A user_foo@serverB "my_cmd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have netcat installed on server1.com (you probably do), you may want to use the ssh directive `ProxyCommand` to seamlessly hop across server1.com; thus, when you press Ctrl+C, it will only terminate the command on server2.com, not your SSH session.

Example of your `~/.ssh/config` (create the file if it doesn't exist; append to end if it does):

```
Host server2.com
  User piskvor
  ProxyCommand ssh -q server1.com nc -q0 server2.com 22
```

What happens here:

- ssh connects to server1.com
- it remotely connects from there to server2.com (using nc)
- which ferries the data through server1.com

This is completely transparent to your ssh client, so you can work with server2.com as if you were connected directly (e.g. SFTP, X forwarding, TCP forwarding, etc.)

For a more detailed explanation (as well as extending this to multiple hops), [see this article](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), or this [similar question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine).

Comment: Thanks. After some more configuration this gives me a nice shortcut to ssh to server2: "ssh server2.com"... However, if I use "ssh server2.com tail -f file.log" I end up having the same problem. Ctrl+c kill the ssh connection, and leaves the tail process running. I want to run this command in a script, which opens multiple windows etc... so, I can not just ssh to server2 and manually type in the tail command.

Comment: Accepting your answer, as I never found myself wanting to script tail commands on remote servers, as connecting got much easier using your suggested configuration... I guess there is no more need to find an answer for my initial question