# Can I use ProxyCommand to run arbitrary commands on a target server via a jumpbox/middle server?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

At work, we have a number of servers that we can only SSH into from our *jumpbox* server.

Every now and then I need to execute a command on these servers. For example, if I want to execute `df -H` on *server-1*, I run this command:

```
ssh jumper@jumpbox 'ssh admin@server-1 ''dh -H'''
```

Our `jumpbox` has the keys to SSH into `server-1`, and my local workstation has the keys for SSHing into the `jumpbox`.

In order to simplify this, I have written a script called `jumpbox.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh jumper@jumpbox @
```

Then I can simply run

```
jumpbox.sh ssh admin@server-1 dh -H
```

To achieve the same goal. Is there a way I can achieve this by configuring my environment (e.g. by editing `~/.ssh/config`), rather than
using this custom script?

I have found [a](http://backdrift.org/transparent-proxy-with-ssh) [few](http://sergbelokamen.com/post/66633304441/transparently-proxy-ssh-connection-via-an-intermediary) articles 
as well as [some](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366652/ssh-to-machine-through-a-middle-host) on StackOverflow 
that discuss how using `ProxyCommand` we can achieve this, but I can't seem to make it work.

First of all, the manual say this about `ProxyCommand`:

> Specifies the command to use to connect to the server. *The command string extends to the end of the line, and is 
>   executed with the user's shell.*

If I am not wrong, this means that if I have the following configuration:

```
Host server-1
    ProxyCommand  ssh jumper@jumpbox nc %h %p
```

And then on my shell I execute

```
ssh server-1 dh -H
```

Then `dh -H` will be ignored. So looks like `ProxyCommand` is helpful in opening a new interactive SSH session, but not running one off commands. Is this correct?

Also I don't quite understand what is `nc`'s role here?

To summarize, my question is:

*Is there a way to configure my environment using `~/.ssh/config`, etc. so that when
I run `ssh admin@server-1 dh -H`, for example, the command is run through the `jumpbox` server?*

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can achieve by ProxyCommand. From your Work Station, try to run "ssh admin@server-1 dh -H".. it will be executed by exec ssh -q  nc server-1 22... So Proxycommnad helps to connect the client server, once connected, the client shell will execute the command that your've given from your workstation.

so .. your ~/.ssh/config should have the below entry

Host server*
    ProxyCommand  ssh -q jumper@jumpbox nc %h %p
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no