# getting :Failed to create home directory “/home/user1”, Operation not applicable while connecting using ssh

Tags: ssh

I am not interested to fix this issue, I am using this server as jump server to get to another server in dmz I have tried:

1. `ssh   server1  2> >/dev/null`
2. `ssh   server1 -q`
3. `ssh -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server1 2>/dev/null`

And other variations, but still getting the same message. Please help me to suppress this message while connecting using `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -NT jump-box" dmz-server
```

It should prevent `sshd` server on jump-box from creating interactive session and probably also the message should disappear. You can set up these options into your `ssh_config` as described in [different answers](https://superuser.com/questions/940554/multi-hop-ssh-connection/940638#940638).