# Run command when a specific ssh config connect fails

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tunnel

This is a bit of a long shot, but what would be the best way of getting ssh to, if a connection fails, run a command, and then retry to connect.

To share my use case, I am ssh-ing over an ssh tunnel to access a computer behind a firewall, meaning in my ~/.ssh/config is:

```
Host tunnel
    HostName 192.168.1.27

Host target
    HostName localhost
    Port 2003
```

and in order for `ssh target` to work, I would need to first have `ssh -N -L 2003:localhost:22 tunnel` being executed in the background. I've resolved to doing this with a single command: `screen -d -m ssh -N -L 2003:localhost:22 tunnel`.

It's not too annoying to run that command when `ssh target` fails, but it would be nice if ssh could somehow automatically run it when the connection fails.

Comment: Already answered in a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3404274/3637404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better solution then tunnelling is using ProxyCommand, as described here: [Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine)

To match your use case:

```
Host tunnel
  HostName 192.168.1.27
Host target
  HostName localhost
  Port 2003
  ProxyCommand ssh tunnel -W %h:%p
```

or

```
  ProxyCommand ssh tunnel nc %h %p
```

Then doing just `ssh target` does everything for you.