# I can ssh to server C on server B, but got timeout when I ssh to server C tunneling through server B

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

Suppose I am on computer A and eventually I want to ssh into server C. However, server C has IP restrictions so I have to ssh to server B first as a gateway.

The situation is:
1) if I first ssh into server B, and ssh into server C under the shell of server B, I could get in.
2) if I use the method in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine) (I tried both answers, by ephemient and by Wesley), then I got a "timed out".

When I use `ssh -vvv`, the ssh stuck at

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ****
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp   SHA256:****
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:****
```

when using key authentication. And ssh would stuck at

```
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
```

when using password authentication.

Interestingly, when I input an incorrect password, the remote host can find that out and prompt me to enter password again.

Does any one know what could be the possible reason for this time out?
Thanks!

Comment: What authentication are you using on the C server? Is it your local key or some key on the server B?

Comment: @Jakuje: When I log in from shell of Server B, I use password. When I log in from computer A (tunneling through server B),  I use the local key on computer A (and also tried the password).