# VSCode SSH with multiple hops

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to edit code on a remote machine. The VSCode SSH extension offers this feature, but I can only get it to work for a single hop. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Click on 'Remote Explorer' in VSCode sidebar
- Click `+` for 'Add Target'
- Enter the multiple-hop ssh command: `ssh -A userA@hostA ssh userB@hostB`
- Select `~/.ssh/config` as the SSH config file to update
- When I do this, only the information from the first SSH hop is entered into the `config` file:

```
Host hostA
  HostName hostA
  ForwardAgent yes
  User userA
```

How can I get VSCode to correctly establish a multiple-hop ssh connection?

Answer (score 20):

I believe the cleanest way to do this would be to add the following in the `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host HostA
  HostName hostA
  User userA

Host HostB
  HostName hostB
  User userB
  ProxyJump HostA
```

Now you just need to type `ssh HostB` to reach the remote machine.

HostA will act as middle man between you and HostB.

Comment: This seems a better answer. Fyi host A is middle man here between you and server. Just putting it here as I was confused and spent 20 minutes figuring why it didn't work.

Comment: Happy I could help. I improved the answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: I get an error : posix_spawn: No such file or directory

Comment: Can one make this work if they also have to go through an extra first hop which is a plain telnet connection?

Comment: You should be able to make as many hops as you need.   You can have a HostC define a ProxyJump through a HostB, and have HostB define a ProxyJump through HostA.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This seems to be the simplest and most elegant solution

Answer (score 7):

After reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/107681/917655), I updated the `~/.ssh/config` file as follows:

```
Host hostB
  HostName hostB
  User userB
  ProxyCommand ssh userA@hostA -W %h:%p
```

and I was able to connect.