# VSCode SSH triple hop on different usernames and ports

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh-tunnel

I'm working on code on my server which is within my corporate network firewall. The way I do this is as follows: I ssh to my home gateway `myhomegateway` with user `user1` and port `11111`  which has a permanent reverse tunnel with my workstation `workstation` with user `user2` on port `22222`. Then through the workstation I can ssh to the server `servername` with user `user3` and port `33333`.

I can access my server using this single command where I need to enter 3 different passwords one after the other:

```
ssh -A -t myhomegateway -l user1 -p 11111 ssh -A -t localhost -l user2 -p 22222 ssh -A servername -l user3 -p 33333
```

However instead of working with vim or nano, I'd like to work with VSCode using the [Remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension.
I have seen similar posts e.g. [VSCode SSH with multiple hops](https://superuser.com/questions/1528212/vscode-ssh-with-multiple-hops) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780250/does-vscode-remote-support-double-ssh that configured the `.ssh\config` file by adding `ProxyJump` but for some reason it doesn't work for my case where I have non-standard SSH ports and different usernames. My file currently is as follows. Can anyone help with this? (My VSCode OS is Windows)

```
host myhomegateway
  HostName myhomegateway.IP
  User user1
  Port 11111
  ProxyJump reversetunnel

host reversetunnel
  HostName localhost
  User user2
  Port 22222
  ProxyJump server

host server
  HostName servername 
  User user3
  Port 33333
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this dude?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. :(

Comment: Facing the same problem... :(