# Trying to mount remote directory using sshfs: filesystem unresponsive

Tags: ssh, filesystems, proxy, sync, sshfs

I'm trying to mount a remote directory using sshfs. I've got my `.ssh/config` set up so that I can ssh into my user on the remote machine like so

```
ssh wdev
```

The remote directory in question (let's suppose it's located at `~/runtime` for the remote user `remoteuser`) is pretty large (it's ye old big C++ project, complete with build files and a lot of folders).

From what I've read online, I should be able to mount `runtime` to a folder `~/local-mount` (which I've already created) like so:

```
$ sshfs wdev:/home/myuser/runtime ~/local-mount
```

However when I run this, there's no output whatsoever. Running `sshfs` with the `-d` flag is slightly more informative

```
$ sshfs -d wdev:/home/myuser/runtime ~/local-mount
FUSE library version: 2.9.7
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
```

However at this point the output stops. What's more, it seems to freeze up other things too. If I open up another shell and try to `ls ~/local-mount`, it just stays suspended until I interrupt with `Ctrl+c`. This happens even if I just trigger autocompletion on the directory name from my shell

```
ls ~/loca<TAB>
```

`nautilus` won't even open. All these symptoms persist until I interrupt the process running `sshfs`, at which point everything resumes normally. Can someone help me with getting this to run properly?

---

I should note that while mangling the hostname in the `sshfs` command will immediately yield an error, I can mangle the remote folder name however I want and I'll still get the same behavior

---

For what it's worth, I've attached my `~/.ssh/config` below. My connections to `wdev` actually get forwarded through the proxy `wsl`, if it's relevant

```
# --- init_sd_card generated ---

# Use the key for all hosts
IdentityFile /home/local_user/.ssh/id_rsa

Host wsl
    User remote-user
    HostName 10.0.0.211
    Port 2222

# https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine
Host wdev
    User remote-user
    HostName 10.240.115.106
    ProxyCommand ssh wsl -C -W %h:%p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my usage was correct and there was an error in my ssh config. The things that tipped me off was that ssh'ing into `wdev` worked fine, but trying to ssh into `wsl` didn't work.

I'm still not sure what was causing that, but I ended up purging/reinstalling the ssh server on `wsl` and that seems to have fixed things