# How to mount remote SSHFS via intermediate machine? Tunneling?

Tags: ssh, mount, remote, tunnel, sshfs

I would like to mount a remote file system (A) using SSHFS, but sometimes I have IP address, access from which is not allowed. So my plan is to access it via another machine (B) in that network. Do I need to mount A on B and then to mount B (and A) on my local computer? Is there a better way to do it?

**Update**

Just to clarify the procedure:

First, I make a tunnel

```
ssh -f user@machineB -L MYPORT:machineA:22 -N
```

And then I mount the remote file system

```
sshfs -p MYPORT user@127.0.0.1:/myremotepath /mylocalpath
```

Is it correct?

How do I destroy the tunnel when I am done?

Comment: better way to set up tunnel is to have connection to B from *GNU screen* window using *ssh user@machineB -L 2222:machineA:22 -N* so you can easily kill it with ^C

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yeah tunneling. You connect machine B, create local tunnel (-L) to SSHd port of machine A then *sshfs* to *localhost* to the port of newly created tunnel.

Comment: Is the following command the right way to do that? `ssh -f user@machineB -L 25:machineA:25 -N`

Comment: yes if you have sshd listening to port 25 on machine A. then you'll just have to *sshfs -p 25 user@127.0.0.1:/path /localpath*

Comment: Aha, so for default ssh setup I need `ssh -f user@machineB -L 22:machineA:22 -N`, right?

Answer (score 28):

You can use option `ssh_command` of `sshfs` to do the trick:

```
sshfs ma: /mnt -o ssh_command='ssh -t mb ssh'
```

Unmount with the usual

```
fusermount -u /mnt
```

Sorry this is 7 years late...

Comment: With the new -J option in Openssh 1.1 it is something along: sshfs ma:  /mnt -o ssh_command='ssh -J mb'

Comment: I wasn't able to get this syntax to work on my particular network configuration, but the `-o proxyjump` syntax did.

Answer (score 12):

This is what works for me on HighSierra 10.13.6, SHFS version 2.5 (OSXFUSE SSHFS 2.5.0) OSXFUSE 3.10.4. FUSE library version: 2.9.7

Based on Rodrigo Farias's answer above + clemisch and Ohad Rubin comments for noting the -J option:

```
sshfs -p port finalserver_username@finalserver:/path/to/folder/on/finalserver/ /local/mount/point -o ssh_command='ssh -J intermediate_server_username@intermediate_server:port'
```

Comment: If it works for you why do you have to base it on answers and comments?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The -t options worked on a previous setup, but not on this one. That's what I meant by  "works for me on ..". The answer is a combination of the original answer by Rodrigo with the comments from Ohad and Clemisch, hence the attribution.

Comment: Thanks! This was the only solution that worked for me in Catalina.

Comment: Currently using an old mb pro with Mojave.  Used macports to install sshfs.  Was able to connect to a server in a VPC going through a gateway box using this method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your connection scheme:
`Your machine --> Host B --> Host A`

Our solution will use Proxy Jump, introduced in [OpenSSH 7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3), so you'll need to check that your version is newer with:

```
ssh -V
```

Then you need to [configure properly](https://superuser.com/a/170592/) your ~/.ssh/config. For example, if **machineB** is available with a password login from **machineA** :

```
machineB
    HostName {machineB ip address}
    User {machineB username}
    Port {machineB port-number}
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{machineB private ssh key}

machineA
    ProxyJump machineB
    Hostname {machineA ip address, maybe in local network}
    User {machineA username}
    Port {machineA port-number}
```

Finally, create your mountpoint and [add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131720/) line to /etc/fstab

```
machineB:{machineB mount path}  {your local mountpoint}  fuse.sshfs delay_connect,_netdev,user,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,identityfile={local path to machineB private key},default_permissions,uid={local user uid},gid={local user gid} 0 0
```

Comment: Does this have any benefit vs. using only `-o ssh_command="ssh -J machineB"` ?