# Mount a filesystem (using FUSE) with SSH through two computers

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, sshfs, fuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mount remote SSHFS via intermediate machine? Tunneling?](https://superuser.com/questions/139023/how-to-mount-remote-sshfs-via-intermediate-machine-tunneling)

I can mount a filesystem over SSH directly with

```
$ sshfs hostname: mountpoint
```

However, in order to access a certain machine from an outside network, I must SSH through a chain of two computers.

```
localhost $ ssh hostname1
...
hostname1 $ ssh hostname2
```

Is there a way to mount a virtual filesystem with FUSE/SSHFS on my local machine to access a directory on hostname2?

Answer (score 1):

You would set up SSH Tunnel and then you would mount the filesystem. I think your questions is a duplicate of [How to mount remote SSHFS via intermediate machine? Tunneling?](https://superuser.com/questions/139023/how-to-mount-remote-sshfs-via-intermediate-machine-tunneling?rq=1)