# Work blocks OpenSSH but not putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, openssh

My place of work  has a corporate firewall which blocks openSSH but not putty. I'm running Ubuntu, so it's no problem for me to use putty instead, but I have remote servers mounted using sshfs, which doesn't work due to the openSSH block. Is there a way I can either unblock openSSH for use with sshfs, or have sshfs use putty rather than openSSH?

Comment: I'm connecting to the same server on the same port (22). In addition, I can connect over openssh at locations other than my work. After doing a whireshark analysis of a connection over openssh and putty, I believe that it blocks it by protocol name (Putty's protocol is named "SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.65" and openssh's is named "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1"), though I don't know too much about networking so I'm not sure if this is possible. I tried running the SSH server on a non-standard port but it didn't work.

Comment: Also, the error I receive over openSSH client is "ssh_packet_read: Connection reset by peer." The server's openSSH log says "fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]".

Comment: I'm running ubuntu though, so that solution doesn't answer my question. Also, I'm not asking how to mount an sftp drive - I can do that already with sshfs, I'm asking how can I do this with a firewall that blocks ssh.

Comment: Questions that seek ways to get around security configurations for a network are actually not on topic here at Superuser.  [issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The way to overcome a workplace restriction is to raise the issue with management and make a case for the business benefit of the change. It's the owners'/shareholder's property you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I agree @RedGrittyBrick comment which you need to request for approval, since it might be the case this policy(to allow only putty) is just for temporary use only for IT admins.

Nevertheless, you can try sshfs over ssh-tunnel if you really need to.

1. Establish ssh tunnel between your PC and server. ([How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974131/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-using-putty-in-windows))
2. Mount the remote file system ([How to mount remote SSHFS via intermediate machine? Tunneling?](https://superuser.com/questions/139023/how-to-mount-remote-sshfs-via-intermediate-machine-tunneling))