# scp "pipe" files via intermediate host

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

This is sort of a level-up from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host). Suppose that I am on computer `A` and want to send files to a computer `C`. We each have separate access to a host `B`.   `A` and `C` can not communicate directly, and `B` cannot initiate a connection to either.

Is there a way I could pipe a large file to SSH and create some sort of stream which I could then tell the user of computer `C` to connect to? The file is larger than the available space on `B`. My current solution is to `split` the large file, upload each segment in turn, and when user at `C` has finished downloading one chunk notifies me, I delete the chunk and upload the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send data from A to C, but neither computer can connect to the other, but they can both connect to B. B can't connect to anyone.

**One** solution is using port forwarding. C can forward from a port on B to their SSH port (port 22):

```
ssh -R 1088:localhost:22
```

1088 is arbitrary, choose a port that isn't already in use. By default this port is only available on that local machine, i.e., only processes running on B can connect to it.

now a user on A can connect directly to C:

```
ssh B "ssh -p 1088 localhost"
```

Or for example, this command will send a file from A to C:

```
cat infile | ssh B "ssh -p 1088 localhost \"cat > outfile\""
```

Alternatively, A could have forward their port, allowing the user on C to initiate the copy.

**Another** solution is to use named pipes. On B, execute:

```
mkfifo named_pipe
```

Then on A you can send data into the pipe with:

```
cat infile | ssh B "cat > named_pipe"
```

This command will hang until someone opens the other end of the pipe and reads the data out of it. For example, the user on C can do:

```
ssh B "cat named_pipe" > outfile
```

This will send the file from A through B to C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) for them to pull.  Make sure to create the pipe first, have them connect from computer `C`, and then start streaming to it.