# Transferring files from one server to another via a third machine, using key not password

Tags: linux, scp

I want to transfer files from one server to another.

```
scp -r user@11.11.11.22:/home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts
```

When I run this command I received an answer that I need to put password for the `server.com.` But I'm not using the password, I'm using a key. how I can insert the key instead of the pass?

Comment: Is the key on the local machine? I think unless you use [`-3`](https://superuser.com/a/401245/432690), your local key doesn't matter.

Comment: The issue is you are using a third machine — your local machine — to copy files from `11.11.11.22` to `server.com`. I am sure if you login directly to `11.11.11.22` you can then run this command fine: `scp -r /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts`.

Comment: But I logged on via putty to the server from which I want to send the files

Comment: @ririririri If you are logged directly into `11.11.11.22` then your command doesn’t need the [user]@[hostname] stuff. It can just be `scp -r /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts`. In fact, drop the `-r` — since you are just copying one file — and run it like this: `scp /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you are using a third machine — your local machine — to copy files from `11.11.11.22` to `server.com`. I am sure if you login directly to `11.11.11.22` you can then run this command fine:

```
 scp -r /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts
```

But if you are actually logged directly into `11.11.11.22` then your command doesn’t need the `[user]@[hostname]` stuff. It can just be:

```
scp -r /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts
```

In fact, drop the `-r` — since you are just copying one file — and run it like this:

```
scp /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts
```

Just be sure you use the `-A` option when SSHing into `11.11.11.22`. As [the SSH man page states](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> “Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection. This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.”

Meaning your key from your local machine is passed along during the SSH session. So you initially login to `11.11.11.22` like this:

```
 ssh -A user@11.11.11.22
```

You can then cleanly login to `server.com` like this:

```
ssh user@server.com
```

Which then means this SCP command should work without prompting for a password:

```
scp -r /home/filename.php user@server.com:/home/scripts
```

Comment: It still asks me to enter the password. Can it be that the server needs to give me permission to send files?

Comment: @ririririri “Can it be that the server needs to give me permission to send files?” As long as you can login, you should be good. When you are logged into `11.11.11.22` what happens when you just run `ssh user@server.com` and login to that other server?

Comment: when i type ssh user@server.com it again asks me for password, but i dont have password, im using key to login

Comment: @ririririri So when you initially SSH into `11.11.11.22`, I recommend using `ssh -A user@11.11.11.22`. And then when you are logged in, do `ssh user@server.com` and you should be able to login. That `-A` “Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection. This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.” Meaning it passes your keys from your local host to that connection. Meaning — if you use `ssh -A` — that when you are logged into `11.11.11.22`, the SSH agent will be aware of your key and you can then cleanly do an `ssh user@server.com` and log yourself in.

Comment: I did it, but still asks me for password.

Comment: @ririririri Then there are aspects of this setup you are not explaining well. Please look at the output of `ssh -A -v user@11.11.11.22` as well as the output of `ssh -v user@server.com` to see if that verbose output gives you any clues.

Comment: debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1002)

Comment: @ririririri If you genuinely want help, you need to provide these details and specifics to your question. The reality is you are missing a lot of details in your question. Without those details, nobody here can help you.