# SCP Using Local Machine as Jump Host

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I want to transfer a file between two remote servers (R1 and R2) which can't talk to each other. My machine (let's say L) can talk to both R1 and R2. Is there a way to use my local machine as the intermediate host?

Here's the situation

```
L ----> R1
L ----> R2
R1 ---x--> R2
```

I want to send files from R1 to R2 using L.

```
R1 ----> L ----> R2
```

I found some resources [here](http://mperdikeas.github.io/networking.html.files/scp-a-file-through-jump-host.html) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host), but can't figure out the syntax to use local machine as intermediate host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp` has the ability to copy files from one remote host to another remote host:

```
scp user1@host1:/some/file user2@host2:/some/directory/
```

This copies `/some/file` on the first host to `/some/directory` on the second host.

Normally, `scp` implements this by connecting to host1 and invoking scp on host1 to transfer files to host2. You say this won't work for you.

[`scp` has an option](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#3) to transfer files using between two remote hosts, using the local host as an intermediary:

```
 scp -3 user1@host1:/some/file user2@host2:/some/directory/
     ^^
```

When run in this fashion, the local `scp` instance will open two connections, one to each host. One connection will send `/some/file` to the local host. The other connection will receive files and write them to `/some/directory`. The local `scp` instance relays data between the two connections. This should do what you want.