# How do I create a service that directs traffic to an SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have the following scenario:

1. A service listening on port 6678 on Computer C
2. Only computer B can access computer C via ssh
3. Computer B is accessible globally

I would like to do the following:

Setup a service on a Computer "A" that listens on port 6678 that would end up being redirected to computer "C" and to its listening service.  I understand that I need to create an SSH tunnel through multiple hops. Such as `A -> B -> C`.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops) helped me a lot, but the problem is: It does not set a socket on "A" that may be accessed globally. I tried to mess around with `ssh -D` to set a binding socket, e.g.

```
ssh -D *:6678 -p 6678 localhost
```

but it does not seem to do a trick.

What would be the best option for creating a multiple-hop SSH tunnel and at the same time setup a listener on computer "A" to allow traffic to?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
ssh -g -L 6678:computerC:6678 computerB
```

If you run this on computer A it will open a port on computer A and traffic will be redirected to computer C using the ssh connection to computer B. This assumes that computer B can access port 6678 on computer C directly. You may want to try this without the -g option first if you only need access to computer C from computer A. If you need to grant access to computer C to multiple machines you will need the -g options and possibly and adjustment to your firewall rules.

Comment: To set this up as a service, [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) can help by automatically restarting ssh if the tunnel should stop passing traffic.

Comment: I haven't heard of autossh before. Would be a good idea since I have seen port scans kill ssh port forwarding.

Comment: I use daemontools to auto-restart my SSH tunnels, same idea, very handy.