# ssh tunnelling port forwarding

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have three computers, A, B, C. A is the computer I'm working on, C is the remote computer I'd like to access. However C can only be accessed through B. Only B has a ssh server, and only A has a ssh client.

What command am I to use (preferably on A) so that I can connect to C (port 80) through B ? For example B should forward all incoming port 12345 to C:80.

I know this is a common question and I found a ton of commands on google but none seemed to work.

Once it is set up, I'm supposed to just use localhost:5678 on A, which connects to B:1234, and then forwards to C:80.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the `sshd` daemon is set to disallow port-forwarding to other machines or to disallow port-forwarding at all. Anyway, the correct command to issue at `A` to access `C` at port 80 as follows:

```
ssh -L localhost:5678:<ip-or-name-of-C>:80 <ip-or-name-of-B>
```

After the `ssh` session is established you connect to localhost:5678 to get connected to C:80.  If you wish any inbound connection to the host A:5678 be forwarded to C:80, then remove `localhost:` from the command above.

If the port-forwarding to other hosts is disabled at `B`, then you could try the chaining, described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops?rq=1)

Comment: This is it, thank you. However, I do get to the prompt of B. If I want to avoid that, I have to add -nN, right ?

Comment: the `-N` is enough to not start a remote shell. if you wish to put ssh into background then, yes, add the `-n` switch