# How to configure SSH tunnel with same intermediate/end server?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have [read this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/557141/ssh-tunnelling-port-forwarding) and the [SSH section of the Debian handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/download/stable/debian-handbook.pdf#page=220), and I am trying to do something similar. But there is a slight complication in that I really only have two servers in play.

**The Setup**

To log on to my work machine from my home machine I require two steps. First I log on to `workip.com` using a weird `sshuser` username, and then I can log into my own account.

Step 1: `ssh sshuser@workip.com`

Step 2: `ssh myusername@localhost -p 32000`

Which will provide access to my work station. I am do not know why the network is set up this way, but I cannot change it.

Note that running the command

`ssh myusername@lworkip.com -p 32000`

directly from my home machine *does not work*, so I need to go through the tunnel.

**What are you trying to do?**

I need to be able to run the command `ssh myusername@localhost:9090` from my home machine to gain direct access to `myusername@workip.com`. This tunnel is proving hard to configure.

**What have you tried?**

As suggested by the question above and the handbook, I tried configuring the tunnel from my home machine using two different commands (neither work):

`ssh -L localhost:9090:workip.com:32000 sshuser@workip.com`

`ssh -L localhost:9090:localhost:32000 sshuser@workip.com`

Unfortunately, when I try to run the command `ssh myusername@localhost:9090` from home, I receive the error message `could not resolve localhost:9090: Name or service not known`, which indicates my solution is incorrect.

Comment: Just want to double check.. have you tried: `ssh myusername@localhost -p 9090`?

Comment: I am incredibly silly, your comment is spot on. Please write it below so I can mark this post as resolved. Also, I should note that `ssh -L localhost:9090:localhost:32000 sshuser@workip.com` is the  command to set up the tunnel correctly.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops