# Vnc and ssh tunnelling not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vnc

I am trying to access my work computer (server C) via vnc. I have root on this machine. I can't access it directly so I have to go via server B. I have done the following steps.

First on my local machine I run

> ssh -L 5900:serverC:5900 user@serverB

and then on serverC I ran

> x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0

However when I then do

> vinagre localhost::5900

on my local machine it says it can't connect.

Both my local machine and serverC are running ubuntu. serverB is running CentOS and I don't have root on it.

What am I doing  wrong?

If nothing, what's a good way to diagnose the problem?  Is there some way to tell if serverB has port forwarding disabled?  Is there a way to do port forwarding in user space?

Comment: I think it should be `vinagre localhost::0`. To my knowledge, the command line for vnc clients takes a display number and maps it to a port number by adding 5900 to it.

Comment: @JosephR Thanks.  That's not the problem sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works although is a little complicated.

```
ssh -v -L 1200:serverC:22 user@serverB
ssh -v -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -p 1200 user_from_serverC@127.0.0.1
x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0
vinagre localhost::5900
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at option #2 in the accepted answer on this related SuperUser question: [An SSH tunnel via multiple hops](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops)

Option #1 probably won't work for you unless you can send direct traffic from server B to server C outside of an ssh connection.

Option #3 won't work for you because it assumes that you're able to set up an ssh connection directly to server C.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that 5900 is blocked on serverC it seems. I found  way round it though.