# Vnc using port forwarding from windows

Tags: windows, putty, vnc, port-forwarding

In order to vnc from home into my work desktop running linux I have to take some quite complicated steps.  I have to first connect to the work server linux box and from there I can connect to my work desktop. You can't connect directly to the work desktop at all from the outside world.  To add to the problems the work computer has port 5900 filtered so I need can't connect on that port even from the work server.

I can work out how to do this from my home linux machine using ssh port forwarding (e.g. ssh -L) but how can I do it from windows?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a Repeater on your linux. It manages connections to other computers on the network (Proxy) by had a listening port. Then you can connect by using a **proxy address** (your Linux server's ip and the Repeater port) in the proxy field, and the **name** of the VNC server in the address field.

Download the Linux VNC Repeater: http://code.google.com/p/vncrepeater/downloads/list
Full guide; Not to setup Linux Repeater: http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-repeater.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Linux machine set up properly, you can do it the same way on Windows by installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which has an OpenSSH package available. Just download the [Cygwin setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) and make sure the `openssh` package is selected for installation.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid cygwin. Can it be done using putty?

Comment: PuTTY supports port forwarding via `Connections -> SSH -> Tunnels`, and it works fine for one hop at least.

Comment: How do you use that to forward 5900 on the work server to 5901 on the work desktop for example?

Comment: I thought you said you'd worked out how to do this on Linux, but if not, I'd suggest looking at http://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops and use [Plink.exe](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) if you want to avoid OpenSSH. You can apply the same multi-hop concepts to the graphical PuTTY, but it'd be less automated -- I think you'd have to set up one session that forwards from the work server to the work desktop, and then another session that connects to the work desktop via the first tunnel.