# Can you do continous ssh tunneling?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I saw [here](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops) a way to do two ssh hops

> ssh -L 9998:host2:22 -N host1 
>   ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N -p 9998 localhost

I think I understand what one line does, but not how they work together. Can you keep on doing this to have tunnels within tunnels for many hops? Would it be like this?

> ssh -L 9997:host3:22 -N host2 
>   ssh -L 9998:host2:22 -N host1 
>   ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N -p 9998 localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to forward via SSH.  AKA what you are trying to do.

The `-L lport:host:hport` syntax makes it so that if you connect to `lport` on your starting host you will connect to `hport` on host.

So say you are on `hostA`.  and you want to get to the http (port 80) on `hostD` that isn't reachable except by `hostC` that is only reachable by `hostB` and that is reachable by your starting `hostA`.

You can run (from `hostA`):

> ssh -L 8080:localhost:8081 hostB

then on that `hostB` login run:

> ssh -L 8081:localhost:8082 hostC

then on that `hostC` login run:

> ssh -L 8082:localhost:80 hostD

You can then (on `hostA`) access `localhost:8080` and connect to `hostD`'s port 80.

Note: you can use the same 8080 on all as you are only using that port once per machine.  I just upped the port numbers each connection to better show the correlations between the ports.

The other thing to keep in mind is the host (between the two :'s) is in the context of the machine you are ssh'ing into.  so if `hostC` had direct access to `hostD`'s port 80, you could have instead done the following:

You can run (from `hostA`):

> ssh -L 8080:localhost:8081 hostB

then on that `hostB` login run:

> ssh -L 8081:hostD:80 hostC

Comment: Did you mean "if hostB had direct access to hostD's port 80?" Because I thought we already said hostD isn't reachable except by hostC.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. We can't access port 80 on hostD. So with this method does the content stay encrypted on each hop point? Or does hostB decrypt it and reencrypt? Ideally it would stay encrypted and hostB and hostC would just serve as forwarders that could repeat or encrypt with an additional layer.

Comment: @Steve can we do similarly with the ssh_config file Proxy command?