# Relay two SSH connections together

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have three machines:

1. I have physical access to `localhost`
2. I want to ssh into `host1`. However, it is behind carrier-grade NAT, so I can't ssh directly to it from `localhost`
3. `relayhost` is set up to help me connect from `localhost` to `host1`

I want to ssh from each `localhost` and `host1` to `relayhost`, then have `relayhost` relay my ssh connection from `localhost` to `host1`.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops) suggests I can create a tunnel on `relayhost` using `ssh -L` if I know the URI or IP address of `host1`. However, I don't know that because of the carrier grade NAT. So I can imagine a process to relay it like this:

1. On `host1`, `ssh user@relayhost`
2. `relayhost` is watching for this connection and when it sees it says "I'm going to create a tunnel from my port 9999 to this connection"
3. On `localhost`, `ssh 9999:relayhost`

Is this the right way to go about this? How do I do step 2?

Comment: been a while but out of interest, how is relayhost able to get past machineB's carrier grade NAT? the qna you link to doesn't mention anything about carrier grade nat.

Comment: @barlop i think his problem is that both `localhost` and `host1` are behind NAT, he can't circumvent it...

Comment: So say you have  host1, hostX, machineB. You could have the host you want to connect from, connect to some other host that is not behind carrier grade NAT. Call it hostX. Then you could connect host1 to hostX, and have that automatically jump to your MachineB.  So from MachineB I suppose it'd be something like `machineB$SSH -R 1234:127.0.0.1:1000  hostxIP` Then `host1$SSH hostx:1234`   And that should connect indirectly, to machineB on port 1000.

Comment: You haven't even showed yourself trying anything in your question. I mentioned SSH -R and you never did anything with it.  The posted answer also mentions SSH -R and it's still not clear whether you have tried anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any specialized triggers on `relayhost`. All you need to do is use remote port forwarding with `ssh -R` instead of local port forwarding with `ssh -L`.

Now if i understand it correctly - your problem is that neither `localhost` nor `host1` have publicly accessible IP - both are behind NAT. Otherwise it would be easier create tunnel from `host1` to `localhost` with `ssh -R` and then run second SSH connection inside this tunnel.

If we have to use the relay, it can be done in following steps. For clarity let's rename your `localhost` machine to `myhost` now.

1. Run this on `host1`:

   ```
   ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 user@relayhost
   ```

   This will open port `12345` on `relayhost` and when anyone connects to it, the data will be forwarded to SSH port `22` on `host1`.
2. Now you can connect to port `12345` on `relayhost` from `myhost`.

   ```
   ssh user@relayhost -p 12345
   ```

   In case that you have restrictive firewall on `relayhost` that prohibits external access to port `12345`, you can use local port forwarding to open the port locally on `myhost`:

   ```
   ssh -N -L 56789:localhost:12345 user@relayhost
   ```

   And then connect to `host1` from `myhost`:

   ```
   ssh user@localhost -p 56789
   ```

However don't expect to build any permanent networking solution on remote port forwarding (see: https://serverfault.com/q/595323 for future possible problems). You should consider using VPN with server on `relayhost` for long term setup instead.

Comment: Great explanation of how to set up the ssh relay. Can you point to a reference for how I might go about setting up that VPN?

Comment: @ericksonla no he didn't and shouldn't explain to you how to set up a VPN  'cos that's not what you asked about in your question. If you are struggling to set up a VPN then ask a question on that, stating what problem you have

Comment: @ericksonla look up OpenVPN, plenty of tutorials around.