# Remote access raspberry Pi without Port forwarding

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-access

I have raspberry pi which is connected to internet using android hotspot, I want to access the pi over the internet, I cannot forward ports on my android device and i do not want to use third party applications for remote access. Please help!!

Comment: Do you have SSH access to some computer with public IP?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Nope!! I do not have router at home....I can connect internet to my computer using android hotspot ......basically forwarding port is not an option because mobile internet does not allow that

Comment: I meant rather a Linux box or VM in a completely different location with public IP. At work, at your friend's place; or a rented server etc.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes i have another computer with different public ip

Comment: Then [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1272891/432690). In the context of the answer your Raspberry is `host1`, the "computer with different public ip" is `relayhost` and anyone who wants to connect to the Raspberry from the Internet is `myhost`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the link ill definitely try that out......please dont mind but what is 'localhost'

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). Any machine is `localhost` to itself. Referring to a machine like this may be confusing, unless everyone knows exactly which machine you refer to. I guess this is the reason the author of the linked answer used `myhost` instead. But sometimes you need to type `localhost` on some machine to make the machine refer to (e.g. connect to) itself. A sentence "on `myhost` invoke `ssh user@localhost -p 56789`" makes sense, while "on `localhost` invoke …" is ambiguous; because `myhost` is specific in this context and `localhost` is always relative.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am getting time out error on my raspi