# SSH gateway: how to understand ssh -L when remote comes first?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I understand some ssh forwarding basics, but this [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/97007/505495) seems backwards to me. In other words, with 2 hosts, this…

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:10022:localhost:22 root@A
```

…seems to allow a connection from localhost to A. But with 3 hosts, this…

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:10022:A:22 root@B
```

…allows localhost to A though B? Why not localhost to B through A?

The ssh man page seems to describe the 2-hosts option, not the 3-hosts option:

> `-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport`
>
> Whenever a connection is made to the local port or socket, the
>   connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is
>   made to either `host` port `hostport`, or the Unix socket `remote_socket`,
>   from the remote machine.

Comment: a)bind address is not described as a host and cant be a host if it is 0.0.0.0 cos a host cant have that ip. b)And that snippet from the man, is showing what options that can be passed that relate to the  -L, that is why it is not showing the destination host. You would still have a destination host.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what your (mis)understanding really is. I guess the confusion might be because of the word "localhost".

Localhost is a relative term. By definition, in context of any machine `localhost` should refer to this machine exactly. Practically every Linux resolves `localhost` as IP address `127.0.0.1` (I put IPv6 aside) thanks to a proper entry in `/etc/hosts` file. `127.0.0.1` should be assigned to a loopback interface.

In the linked answer most occurrences of the word `localhost` refer to the machine (of three) that is neither `host1` nor `host2`; this is the local machine where commands are invoked. Similarly, when you say "localhost" you probably mean neither `A` nor `B`. From now on let's call this local computer *the client*.

Basically you run this on the client:

```
ssh -L bind_address:port:host:hostport user@server
```

There are two computers involved: the client and the server. Certain parts of the command are valid in context of either the client or the server.

- `ssh -L` is the executable with option that the client understands (the server may not have `ssh` at all).
- `server` is the address of the server from the client's point of view (server may not even be aware it has such-and-such address or name).
- `user` is a username existing on the server (it may or may not exist on the client, irrelevant).
- `bind_address` and `port` are respectively the address (of a network interface) and TCP port on which the client's `ssh` will listen (I don't know if these parameters are even passed to the server at all, the server doesn't need them). In your case `0.0.0.0` means "every available interface".
- `host` and `hostport` are respectively the address and TCP port to which the server should send packets tunneled from the client. These parameters are for the server; **`host` is resolved on the server**. From the client's point of view `host` may be an invalid address or it may resolve to something completely different – it doesn't matter because the client doesn't resolve it at all; `host` is just a character string passed to the server, it means nothing more on the client's side.

**This means if there's a literal `localhost` as this `host` parameter, it is "localhost" from the server's point of view, i.e. the server itself.** It doesn't mean "the client".

---

With this knowledge let's analyze your examples.

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:10022:localhost:22 root@A
```

This captures everything that enters the TCP port `10022` of the client; captured packets will be recreated on the server `A` and destined to `localhost:22`, but `localhost` on the server means "the loopback interface of the server `A` itself".

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:10022:A:22 root@B
```

This captures everything that enters the TCP port `10022` of the client; captured packets will be recreated on the server `B` and destined to `A:22` from there.

Indeed it can be described as "localhost to A though B", where "localhost" means the client.