# SSH connection via intermediate hosts with keys

Tags: ssh, public-key

I read several versions of this question and try to implement them but they did not work so I want to ask my problem with specific details.

Host A: Local Computer

Host B: Intermediate computer ( I can access from my local with using a public key, foo.key

Host C: Final Computer ( I can access it from Host B)

I followed commands like:

```
ssh -J user@hostA.com user@hostB.com
```

But where to put key?

When I try something like:

```
 ssh -i foo.key -J user@hostA.com user@hostB.com
```

It gives error too.

Comment: The actual name for what you're trying to do is an SSH Multi-Hop... see [this](https://superuser.com/a/97007/529800) answer

Comment: Thanks I read this page too before asking, but any of the examples includes a key file. How can I declare the key file while multi-hopping?

Answer (score 3):

The general syntax is `ssh -J <intermediates> <final>`, so according to the information you provided, the actual command should be:

```
ssh -J user@hostB user@hostC
```

If using `-J` or `ProxyJump`, all connections are made by a locally running client, so all private keys must be available on the local system only.

The `-i` option only allows specifying the same keys for all connections. If different hosts (e.g. intermediate vs final) need different keys, you'll need to specify them in `~/.ssh/config` (or load them into ssh-agent):

```
Host hostB
    IdentityFile ~/bastion.key

Host hostC
    IdentityFile ~/finalserver.key
```

(You can specify `User user` and/or `ProxyJump user@hostB` in the same file, if you want.)