Using RealVNC Viewer to connect to a RealVNC Server on a computer I must connect to through an intermediate SSH terminal
Here is a diagram of the network and connection setup that I am working with:

The external network has an Ubuntu server running RealVNC Server (paid version). The simple version of what I want is that I want to open RealVNC Viewer on my Windows computer and connect to the RealVNC Server as if it was a direct connection. I am able to ssh into the remote Ubuntu Server via a sequence of ssh connections through an intermediary tunnel.
How do I accomplish this?

Some additional details are that the Ubuntu computer on the work network has a fixed public IP address that has been whitelisted on the external network. This is how that computer is able to ssh into the computer within the external network. The external network is not able to whitelist my computer at my home network. Thus, it is a requirement that we have this intermediate terminal machine. Currently, what I do is connect to a VNC server running on the work Ubuntu and then VNC again into the external Ubuntu. This is very awkward and slow.

Jump servers are always awkward and slow. no one wants to use them, but when they are required, they are required. you can probably get rid of the VNC session to the jump server if you SSH into it, create a SSH tunnel from the external server to a port on the work server, an ssh tunnel from the home to the tunnel port on the work server, and then point VNC to the local tunnel endpoint. https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops

You can use ssh -R to basically port-forward your VNC traffic to the VNC server like in the examples here under Remote Forwarding: https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example . Make sure that your work policies allow it, since IP whitelists are usually to prevent people accessing stuff from home PCs

Thank you both! I will look into this and experiment. I should be within policy, as no matter what, I have to VPN (with dual factor authentication) into my work's network before SSHing into any of these machines.
